# How do i target APN and FCM with a single AWS Simple Notifiction Service ARN

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, boto3, amazon-sns

Trying to integrate AWS SNS push notification to a mobile app ( ios & android ) but i'm not clear on how to accomplish this.

According to [AWS guide](https://d37o6l6vwst1mv.cloudfront.net/c0f31f576fa38f01c9f8fbab3b5104a868e9742e/assets/images/f2e268dbcbc987402449796c70cf64e6-mobile-push.png) the very first step is to create a platform application endpoint which could either be for *Apple*, *FCM*, *Baidu* ... without any option to select more than one target platform.

After following all steps, i observed that the SNS ARN for FCM platform looks thus:

`arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:8xxxxxxx:endpoint/GCM/app_name/`

#### The problem with that is

it only forwards published notifications to only android device when given the device token.

If i follow same approach for APN, i'll get another SNS ARN for ios which doesn't look resourceful and would result in redundant code for sending push notification to both platforms, duplicated data for device endpoint as then, i would have to create device endpoint for ios and android for a single device

#### How can i publish push notification to both android and ios app using AWS Simple Notification Service ?

Answer (score 0):

Each individual device that registers will get its own SNS endpoint ARN. Android and iOS devices will also need [different payloads](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-send-custom-platform-specific-payloads-mobile-devices.html) sent to them when you call the SNS Publish API.

Many systems will want to lookup a user by ID, and send a message to their device(s). A common pattern for this is to create a DynamoDB table to keep track of some information:

1. The SNS endpoint ARN
2. The type of device
3. An ID associated to the user who owns the device

After your iOS & Android devices successfully register their device tokens with SNS, you should arrange for this information to be stored in your database.